# Polymer 1.0 custom fire event not catching

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have trouble to catch a custom event that fired from my-login Element with a button to the my-overview Element. I really have no clue why this is not working.

**index.html**

```html
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
  <section data-route="login">
    <paper-material id="pmLogin" elevation="1">
      <paper-toolbar>
        <h1 class="paper-font-display1"><span>Login</span></h1>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <my-login id="elLogin"></my-login>
    </paper-material>
  </section>

  <section data-route="overview">
    <paper-material id="pmOverview" elevation="1">
      <paper-toolbar>
        <h1 class="paper-font-display1"><span>Overview</span></h1>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <my-overview id="elOverview"
                   on-call-overview-refresh="reloadOverview">
      </my-overview>
    </paper-material>
  </section>
</iron-pages>
```

**my-login.html**

```js
routeTo: function(route) {
  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
  app.route = route;
  this.fire('call-overview-refresh');
},
```

**my-overview.html**

```js
reloadOverview: function() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you need to declare the `on-*` event handler on the element that actually fired the custom event - in this case `<my-login>`.

Seeing that your `<iron-pages>` is in **index.html**, I suppose the markup is wrapped inside a `<template is="dom-bind"></template>`? If that's the case, your `index.html` might look something like this:

```
<template id="app" is="dom-bind">
  ...
  <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
    <section data-route="login">
      <paper-material id="pmLogin" elevation="1">
        <paper-toolbar>
          <h1 class="paper-font-display1"><span>Login</span></h1>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <my-login id="elLogin"
                  on-call-overview-refresh="callReloadOverview"></my-login>
      </paper-material>
    </section>

    <section data-route="overview">
      <paper-material id="pmOverview" elevation="1">
        <paper-toolbar>
          <h1 class="paper-font-display1"><span>Overview</span></h1>
        </paper-toolbar>
        <my-overview id="elOverview"></my-overview>
      </paper-material>
    </section>
  </iron-pages>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  window.addEventListener("WebComponentsReady", function (e) {
    var app = document.querySelector("#app");
    app.callReloadOverview = function () {
      app.$.elOverview.reloadOverview();
    }
    ...
  });
</script>
```

In the above snippet, when `<my-login>` fires the `call-overview-refresh` event, the `callReloadOverview()` function will be called, which in turns calls `<my-overview>`'s `reloadOverview()` method.

Comment: Yes, you are ready. I use <template is="dom-bind"></template>. Okay, if I get it right, then is the function callReloadOverview() in my-login!? and callReloadOverview() call with document.querySelector('#elOverview').reloadOverview(); the reload function from my-overview. I think then I don't need the event. I simple call the function. Thanks for pointing me to this. But this answered not really the question "How to use custom events between different Elements?".

Comment: `callReloadOverview()` is in your PARENT element, which in your case is your `dom-bind` template. `reloadOverview()` is the method you want to activate in your child element, which in your case is `my-overview`. Actually what I provided is exactly the answer to "use custom events between different elements". You have `child-1` element that fires a custom event, and you want to trigger a function located in `child-2` element. Therefore the way to do it is to listen for `child-1` event in the `parent` element, and forward the call to the function in `child-2` FROM the `parent`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I understand how to use custom fire events.

Comment: @flashback2k14 Why do you need to declace the `on-*` event handler on the element that also fires the event? Shouldn’t events, by default, bubble? It seems very counter-intuitive that you need to catch the event on the same element that fires the event.

Comment: Yes, you are right. this is not really counter intuitive. I don't know why this is the right solution, but it's works as expected. :-)